# Create and use string placeholder programatically

Tags: android, string, kotlin, placeholder

Usually when we use placeholders, we save our string to resources, something like:

```
<string name="stranka">Stranka sa zatvori za %d s</string>
```

And than in our code, we give value like this:

```
snackbarTextView.text = resources.getString(R.string.stranka, remainingSeconds)
```

On the other hand I have a specific situation where I want to create string programmatically and add value to it. But since our resources.getString() takes Int as the first parameter and not a string, I have a problem with adding value to my string (placeholder).

I want to create:

```
var string = "Stranka sa zatvori za %d s"
```

And than add value to my string. How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String?hl=en#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Use %s instead of %d.

Comment: The CommonsWare got the best answer. It's pretty simple: myString.format(3). This is a solution in my case if anyone later needs help